# What is the use of the validate() method in Alamofire.request?

Tags: swift, validation, alamofire

`Alamofire.request(.GET, getUrl("mystuff")).validate()` - what is the use of the `validate()` method? How can I use it to validate server connection issues?

Comment: Have you had the chance to read Alamofire documentation? https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#automatic-validation

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because an answer can be found using Google or similar. In addition, the answer provided does not give an added value. It could be just a comment since the reply has been copied from the Alamofire documentation.

Answer (score 21):

As the [documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#response-validation) mentions, `validate()` **without parameters** checks if the status code is 2xx and whether the optionally provided `Accept` part of the header matches the response's `Content-Type`.

**Example:**

```
Alamofire.request("https://example.com/get").validate().responseJSON { response in
    switch response.result {
    case .success:
        print("Validation Successful")
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

You can provide your **custom validation options** with `statusCode` and `contentType` parameters.

**Example:**

```
Alamofire.request("https://example.com/get")
    .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
    .validate(contentType: ["application/json", "application/xml"])
    .responseData { response in
        [...]
}
```

If you want to check the status code **manually**, you can access it with  `response.response?.statusCode`.

**Example:**

```
switch response.response?.statusCode {
case 200?: print("Success")
case 418?: print("I'm a teapot")
default: return
}
```

Comment: I agree with you that SO can be used as a tool for clarifications. But, your answer does not provide an added value. It's just copied over from the documentation. If instead, you are able to argue something new and useful it could be helpful also for other people.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer. Really appreciated.

Comment: So what if it detects a 4xx/5xx error? Does it go into the `.failure` case, and with what kind of error message to expect (multilingual?) and how do we know which error code?