# Validate Alamofire Response for both HTTP 200 and 500 status codes

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I want to use `Alamofire.request.validate()` to validate http status code and return error If It doesn't pass the rule. As you know, It default check if It is `2xx`. However, I want to add also `HTTP 500`. I tried to do
`Alamofire.request.validate().validate(500)` but It doesn't work. In addition, because It accept sequence only, I can't use `||` operator. How can I achieve this? Thank you.

I got help from below post but can't find anything about my problem.

[What is the use of the validate() method in Alamofire.request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45955823/what-is-the-use-of-the-validate-method-in-alamofire-request)

Comment: `Alamofire.request.validate().validate(500)` is this a typo or you actually called validation twice?

Comment: Yes I called it twice. I find it somewhere on GitHub. However, actually, It is a wrong one. Btw, I don't know why this question gets down vote.

Comment: `var codes = Array(200..<300); codes.append(500); Alamofire.request.validate(statusCode: codes)`? (Note: not tested), or in one line `Alamofire.request.validate(statusCode: Array(200..<300) + [500])`

Comment: Sorry. It doesn't accept array and sequence doesn't have a append option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can make Alamofire validate only `HTTP 200 and HTTP 500` status codes by putting status codes inside an array and give as an input. Hope It helps:

```
Alamofire.request(route).validate(statusCode: [200,500]).responseJSON
```